# Webapi Call resulting in 401 Unauthorized access

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I'm currently making a webapi call through the server side code

```
        var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() {UseDefaultCredentials = true});

        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiurl);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
```

Is there more information I have to include in the client headers to get the call to go through?  This may not be enough information to answer this question but in this case I don't know what I don't know so, I'm not sure what other information to include with this question.  The webapi and the web application are being hosted on the same IIS server instance so the origination of the calls would be from the same root url.  I've enabled CORS in the webapi and just set the params to an asterisk to include all urls for now but that still has no effect.  Any help would be appreciated.

Addtional info:  This is the value of the headers being returned in the response.  Looks like it's using NTLM authentication.

calling the remote webapi from my local GUI

```
IS AUTH: True Username: xxx\xxxxxxxxx
AUTH TYPE: Negotiate
ApiURL: http://testserver1/bbwebapi/api/v1/bbapi/
OK
Pragma:no-cache
Persistent-Auth:true
Cache-Control:no-cache
Date:Mon, 31 Mar 2014 19:42:12 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

The same GUI code on the remote server calling the remote webapi which incidentally are the same server these are the headers

```
IS AUTH: True Username: xxx\xxxxx
AUTH TYPE: Negotiate
ApiURL: http://testserver1/bbwebapi/api/v1/bbapi/
Unauthorized
Cache-Control:private
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
WWW-Authenticate:Negotiate
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
Date:Mon, 31 Mar 2014 19:44:30 GMT
```

The IS AUTH, USERNAME, and AUTHTYPE are from HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated, HttpContext.User.Identity.Name, and HttpContext.User.Identity.AuthenticationType respectively

Comment: No this isn't enough information. What you pass and how depends on what how that webapi is secured. Also CORS is only important for JavaScript based clients.

Comment: Ok... see I didn't know that... so what else do I need to include here to clarify the question.

Comment: I'd recommend looking at the headers that get returned from the response and try finding out what type of authentication mechanism is being used to secure the webapi.

Comment: Added additional info on response headers

Comment: OK. So your service is using Windows NTLM auth to secure the api endpoint. Take a look here and see if this helps http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/integrated-windows-authentication

Comment: So I can call it from running the GUI on my local machine, yet when the same code is deployed to the remote server, the request headers are different, though I am authenticated, but I still get an Unauthorized on the webapi call...  ARGH!